# How to have the placeholder translated in an EntityType?

Tags: forms, translation, symfony4

I'm building a form which has an EntityType element, the problem I have is that I'm unable to have the placeholder translated.

Here is my code:

```
$builder
        ->add('Products', EntityType::class, [
            'mapped' => false,
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => false,
            'required' => false,
            'class' => Product::class,
            'choices' => $options['step']->getProducts(),
            'placeholder' => 'form.mat.alreadyOwned',
            'label' => 'form.mat.alreadyOwned',
            'translation_domain' => 'messages'
        ])
```

When I use the `form.mat.alreadyOwned`translation as the label it works fine, but I would like to use it in the placeholder instead. What am I missing?

Looking forward to any tips or tricks that you have to offer!

[UPDATE]
As pointed out by @gp_sflover I'm not trying to replace the general placeholder, but the one for the empty value. This one only appears if you set `required` to `false`.

Comment: it appears, as if the `placeholder` is translated if the `translation_domain` is set. but that's already done in your case, so I'm wondering what is wrong ... (the translation domain is also used as the translation domain for the placeholder, obviously)

Comment: "it appears, as if the placeholder is translated if the translation_domain is set" Good to know @Jakumi I missed it or this is not mentioned in the docs?

Comment: @Jakumi: I had seen that in some docs, but it hasn't helped. This has had me go slightly mad, reason I'm posting this here.

Comment: @gp_sflover: will try that out when I have a little more time. Not sure how that works.

Comment: it's not mentioned in the docs, but in *some* form rendering cases it's used: https://github.com/symfony/twig-bridge/blob/4f2938ab4c32c02297d552cf2710857b06fabbe9/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L64 however, this might primarily apply  to `<select>` form elements... okay, I just checked in the ChoiceType source, and there just a sub form is added with no particular checks for translation whatsoever, but it inherits the options from the parent ...

Comment: one could be sneaky and override the form rendering of checkbox/radiobutton/option rendering to check if the value is `''` (empty string) and apply translation to the label in that case. I just noticed there exists `choice_translation_domain` which will be used to translate the expanded versions. it defaults to `false` which is to not translate. it obviously is problematic if some labels exist that should not be translated, but would be, if the placeholder should be translated ;o/

Comment: I guess it is indeed easier, to inject the translator into the form type and translate the placeholder that way ;o/

Comment: @Jakumi: if you'll create an answer with a link to some Translator docs I'd be happy to select your answer as the write one ;-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and thought, the places where the `placeholder` is actually used are quite limited in number (as it should be). However, specific placeholder translation is not a special case (sadly).

For every choice in a `ChoiceType` a `ChoiceView` is added. Also for the placeholder [a `ChoiceView` is added, that inherits the options of the form](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/e057a9c89fb6081db23546051517759fb82b0230/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/ChoiceType.php#L74) (which is a somewhat sensible choice for the `ChoiceType`), including the `translation_domain` parameter, which indicates that the choices shall be translated (all of them). There's also a reference in some [twig template that specifically manages the translation in the twig bridge for non-expanded choice types](https://github.com/symfony/twig-bridge/blob/4f2938ab4c32c02297d552cf2710857b06fabbe9/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L64). However, those don't open up a specific best practices answer on how to specifically handle translations for the placeholder in the `ChoiceType`.

For the EntityType, this doesn't change.

So there are a few approaches, some of which might be absolutely utility-free ...

#### translate the placeholder right there when building the form

Although this is conceptually not the most beautiful option, IMHO it's still the most practical one. Essentially, in Symfony 4 [forms can receive dependencies in their constructor](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html#passing-variables-to-the-form-type-template) via auto-wiring, so injecting a [`TranslatorInterface`](https://github.com/symfony/contracts/blob/master/Translation/TranslatorInterface.php) will open up the ability to translate the placeholder with the requests locale (which is automatically set for the translator via event listener):

```
public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator) {
    $this->translator = $translator;
}
```

and in your buildForm you can then use it to translate the placeholder

```
$builder
        ->add('Products', EntityType::class, [
            'mapped' => false,
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => false,
            'required' => false,
            'class' => Product::class,
            'choices' => $options['step']->getProducts(),
            'placeholder' => $this->translator->trans('form.mat.alreadyOwned'),   // <-- change
            'label' => 'form.mat.alreadyOwned',
            'translation_domain' => 'messages'
        ])
```

not to withhold the other options, which in my opinion are almost all overkill...

#### set a  [`choice_translation_domain`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-translation-domain) for *all* entries, including placeholder

obviously, this can and probably will lead to problems, if there ever is an entity that whose choice label matches the key in the translator ... and it is not intended for translation. but it will translate the placeholder with the very same `translation_domain` ...

#### adapt the form rendering and check for the placeholder

this is problematic, since you have to assign the form theme/form rendering to all relevant forms. the placeholder does have a unique name (`'placeholder'`, who would have thought) so it could very well be used to achieve that goal. However, *setting* a different translation domain could very much be challenging. (if you attempt this, it's a bit of a nuisance)

#### write your own entity type (optionally adding own form rendering)

theoretically, you could create your own `EntityType` and handle the placeholder properly there. like ... adding a translation domain to the choice view and sub form and what not. For inspiration/reference consult the [`ChoiceType`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.3/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/ChoiceType.php), [`EntityType`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.3/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/Type/EntityType.php) and [`DoctrineType`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.3/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/Type/DoctrineType.php) (parent type).